# DH-11 Sensor on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, sensors, temperature

I am trying to make my DH-11 sensor work on my raspberry pi but I have not succeeded after several attempts. I followed the following tutorial from Adafruit:

https://learn.adafruit.com/dht-humidity-sensing-on-raspberry-pi-with-gdocs-logging

My attempts were unsuccessful. I just do not get any feedback whatsoever from the sensor. I know that both my DH11/DH22 sensors do work because I do read data from them if I do the same circuit using my arduinos and run a script. I also don't think my raspberry's GPIOs are damaged in any way since I tried with like 5 and I didn't get any data.

I am not trying to log stuff to a google doc like the tutorial does, I am just trying to read data from the sensor using the raspberry.. I have plans to log the data in a server an access it remotely... But for that I have to get readings from the sensor first.

Now, has anyone achieved this? Reading data from a  DH11/DH22 in the raspberry pi? If so, could you tell me which tutorial you followed? I've been looking for some out there but it seems that Adafruit's is by far the most popular one.

Thanks for your help!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

We just found a solution by using the following:

- commenting out the blacklist [as discussed here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=74763&p=535672)
- and, doing the [following as directed here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=97314):

> - better choice: sudo raspi-config
>
>   - elect “Advanced Options”
>   - then either “SPI” or “i2C” and enable the interfaces there
>   - “YES” to load driver modules automatically

Answer (score 0):

I found the details for setting up the DHT22 quite simple.  I followed [thispi.com](http://thispi.com/raspberry-pi-dht22-temperature-humidity-sensor.html) instructions.  I have had issues with the sensor itself and that may be your problem.  My first one was a dud, but the second one I connected worked great.